# Regular expression to parse multiple words

Tags: python, regex, string

I have strings of the form
'Team ScoreA-ScoreB (##%)'

I'm looking for a regular expression or string parsing method that will parse out all of the following:

- TeamA 15-10 (30%)
- Team A 15-10 (45%)
- Te-am A 30-15 (6%)
- Team A's 10-30 (14%)
- Team A. 15-20 (12%)

Basically: {word/words/words abbreviated}{space}{numbers}{hyphen}{numbers}{space}{(}{numbers}{%}{)}

I've got: `/([A-Z])\w+\s\d+-\d+\s\(\d+%\)/g` which will only so far grab one word teams with characters only.

This is for a hobby table-parser. I've also considered trying to split the string (however spaces mean multiple splits and joins) into three parts and concatenating, but it seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse those lines as individual strings, you can use

```
^(.*?)\s*(\d+-\d+)\s*\((\d+%)\)$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iF7xS5/1)

Explanation:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 matching zero or more characters other than a newline as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(\d+-\d+)` - Group 2 one or more digits, hyphen, one or more digits
- `\s*` - ibid.
- `\(` - a literal opening `(`
- `(\d+%)` - Group 3 matching 1 or more digits + `%` symbol
- `\)` - a literal closing `)`
- `$` - end of string

Here is a [demo code](http://ideone.com/iy3D4a):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\s*(\d+-\d+)\s*\((\d+%)\)$')
s = "TeamA 15-10 (30%)\nTeam A 15-10 (45%)\nTe-am A 30-15 (6%)\nTeam A's 10-30 (14%)\nTeam A. 15-20 (12%)"
lines = s.split("\n")
for x in lines:
m = p.search(x)
if m:
    print("%s, %s, %s"%(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3)))
```

The `re.findall` will return lists of tuples. If you have multiline string input, use the `re.MULTILINE` flag when compiling the pattern.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Your sample code works as expected. When I used your re string and did `m = re.search(pattern, str)` and then found the individual elements using `m.group(index)`. I found that the whole string was placed into `m.group(0)` and the individual components were placed behind it.

Comment: Yes, `re.search` finds just one match with all groups.

Comment: Ah, so if I have a list of strings that I would like to parse, should I run this Regular expression against each of them and extract from each of the resulting groups? Or is it more efficient to make a huge block of text for RE to compile on?

Comment: If you have a big file, it is not a good idea to read it all in. If the file is small enough it can be processed as a whole with `p = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\s*(\d+-\d+)\s*\((\d+%)\)$', re.MULTILINE)` and then `p.findall(file_input)`.